# Having trouble passing input from the user into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello :) I am new to python. I have been challenged to build a script that simply converts us measurements to metric ones and vise versa. Should be simple but when I run the script I am getting an error

```
"/home/oily/public_html/script.py
Enter us or international for conversion:us
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oily/public_html/script.py", line 4, in <module>
    begin = input("Enter us or international for conversion:")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'us' is not defined"
```

Why is python not reconizing the us varible that I have assigned? Is it because of the order? I googled this and I am not finding anything I really understand. Thank you beforehand for any assistance.

```
SCRIPT------------------

#!/usr/bin/env python


begin = input("Enter us or international for conversion:")
import begin


us = input("Please enter the value in international:")
international = input ("Please enter the value in us:") 

def start(begin):
    if begin == us:
        return us
    else:
        return international



 def conversion():
    if us:
        return us * 0.0348
    elif int:
        return int * 3.28084
        
print(conversion)
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this. Why do you have `import begin`?

Comment: How are you running your Python script ?

Comment: I read some articles on passing user input into functions and some of them said that it needed that in there to register the varible. Im just getting into loops now so I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: I am running it through command line

Comment: Honestly, there is so much broken with this. I really suggest a tutorial. `return international` is relying on a global lookup, `print(conversion)` is only going to print the function signature (not call it), `import begin` is just... broken, `return int * 3.28084` is trying to multiply by a built-in. Please, just take some time with a tutorial

Comment: I usnderstand the int that should be international. I understand that it is broken. I maybe jumped too fast trying to create a custom script. I have been practicing functions and I have an understanding but never ran anything on an offical server. I guess I just want to know why it does not register the variable us. It will help me with an overall understanding

Answer (score 1):

Only one function needed, need to change the variable `us` and `international` to a `float`:

```
begin = input("Enter 'us' or 'international' for conversion:")

def start():
    if begin == "us":
        us = float(input("Please enter the value in international:"))
        print(us * 0.0348)
    else:
        international = float(input ("Please enter the value in us: "))
        print(international * 3.28084)

start()
```

Comment: Just curious, why did it not reconize the variables that I passed through the function? ELI5?

Comment: Still does not reconize the begin variable

Comment: The reason for the 'us' not defined error is that at the beginning of the script you need to define the us and international variables as None. So the answer above is valid with us = None and international = None at the beginning of the script